# GET and .xq files

Tags: xquery, exist-db

When using exist-db, a GET message will obtain an entire file from a collection (by providing the URI). In the case of a .xq file, however, the same GET message will instead execute the file.

I am wondering if there is anything I can attach to a GET message to cause exist-db to return the file rather than execute it. I should have all the necessary permissions, or I should be able to set them.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are running eXist as a stand-alone server:

"GET accepts the following request parameters, which must be URL-encoded" `_source=yes | no` - which "Specifies whether the query should display its source code instead of being executed" - see the [developers guide online](http://exist-db.org/devguide_rest.xml#d63098e367) for full details & example usage.

eXist sets this capability to 'no' as default in it's config - however you can override this permanently by adding specific files to the `<allow-source></allow-source>` section in the Web-application Descriptor file (descriptor.xml) read from WEB-INF directory of the web application or from the directory specified by the exist.home system property.

Hope that helps.